# What are the advantages of Magnetocardiography?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetostatics

I am reading the book *Bioelectromagnetism* by Malmivuo:

> Difference between the bioelectric and biomagnetic measurements lies
>   in the sensitivity distributions of these methods.
>   Diverse technical properties of these intrumentations which impart to
>   either method specific advantages in certain applications.

So I started to think: what are the advantages of a Magnetocardiogram?

**What are the advantages and disadvantages of Magnetocardiography?**

Comment: I'm not sure this is really a physics question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically electrical measurements rely on skin contact electrodes and do not directly provide detailed information on the electrical characteristics of the heart. On the other hand, magnetic fields go through the skin and provide a direct "view" of the heart and its movement. Electrical pickups are easy. Low field magnetic sensors are difficult to implement and typically require a shielded environments. They are also very costly. The best measurements use [SQUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQUID)

Comment: Yes, I think magnetocardiography can also use SQUIDs.